# Magento 1.7 is not fast in combination with Memcached

Tags: magento, memcached, magento-1.7

Ik hope you will help me to find the perfect settings for my multiple magento webshop with 28 store views.
Yesterday we install memcached on the server with the below local.xml settings.
Actually is the webshop not faster what can be wrong are my settings below oke.

```
<config>
<global>
    <install>
        <date><![CDATA[Mon, 01 Jul 2013 20:04:28 +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
<cache>
     <prefix>koelcenter_</prefix>
     <backend>Apc</backend>
     <slow_backend>Memcached</slow_backend>
     <fast_backend>Apc</fast_backend>
     <slow_backend_options>
          <servers>
               <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
               </server>
          </servers>
          <compression><![CDATA[]]></compression>
          <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
          <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
          <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
          <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
     </slow_backend_options>
     <memcached>
          <servers>
               <server>
                    <host><![CDATA[127.0.0.1]]></host>
                    <port><![CDATA[11211]]></port>
                    <persistent><![CDATA[1]]></persistent>
               </server>
          </servers>
          <compression><![CDATA[]]></compression>
          <cache_dir><![CDATA[]]></cache_dir>
          <hashed_directory_level><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_level>
          <hashed_directory_umask><![CDATA[]]></hashed_directory_umask>
          <file_name_prefix><![CDATA[]]></file_name_prefix>
     </memcached>
</cache>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <frontName><![CDATA[admin]]></frontName>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: The caches are warm right? You won't notice any difference if the page hasn't been hit before.

Comment: Thanks for your response, we are running now already one day but also the homepage who got many hits daily is also not faster.

Comment: It seems like you can use [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/) and [Turpentine](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/2984.html) (Magento plugin for Varnish). That way you have blazing fast shops with the benetis of caching! Varnish is a full page cache.